# NET HELPMSG 3534 Net star doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I use the command net start, the process starts but the service does not start. Of course, the previous command installs it. Suggests: More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534

Please help

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code showing us how the service is written and installed? You might find some additional information in the application event log (e.g. an exception).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have such a right: (

Comment: You might want to contact the developer of the service then if there's nothing in the event log. Message `3534` just translates to 'The service did not report an error'.